# How to enable debug logging for LDAP Extended Module in Wildfly

Tags: java, xml, wildfly

How can I enable debug/trace logging in WildFly 10 for the `LdapExtended` module?

The module is created like the following:

```
<security-domain name="LDAPAuth">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="LdapExtended" flag="required">
            <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="..."/>
            <module-option name="bindDN" value="..."/>
            <module-option name="bindCredential" value="..."/>
            <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="..."/>
            <!-- ... more configuration goes here -->
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

I tried the following configuration but I get no log outputs. My LDAP configuration is not performing the authentication properly and I can't debug.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
    <!-- ... -->
    <logger category="org.jboss.security">
        <level name="DEBUG"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="com.sun.jndi.ldap">
        <level name="DEBUG"/>
    </logger>
</subsystem>
```

Comment: Did you try logging.properties inside your configuration folder?

Comment: I just found out the configuration actually works. It is just not showing in Eclipse.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default the console handler is only set to show `INFO` and higher messages. If you change the console handler level you can see the debug messages on the console as well.

I'd also not advise changing the XML. You can configure all this with the web console or in CLI and no reboot of the server will be required. In other words the changes can be made at runtime.

Here are the CLI commands you'd need to configure the logging you're looking for.

```
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.jboss.security:add(level=DEBUG)
/subsystem=logging/logger=com.sun.jndi.ldap:add(level=DEBUG)
/subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE:write-attribute(name=level, value=DEBUG)
```

Comment: Remove configuration after debugging: `/subsystem=logging/logger=org.jboss.security:remove` (perform for each category)

Answer (score 3):

Actually my configuration was correct, it was not showing in Eclipse only so I got confused.

Go to the `server.log` file or configure it in Eclipse. The following works.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
    <!-- ... -->
    <logger category="org.jboss.security">
        <level name="DEBUG"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="com.sun.jndi.ldap">
        <level name="DEBUG"/>
    </logger>
</subsystem>
```